# Cypress and cypress-metamask plugin issue (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222)

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, web3js, metamask

I am trying to integrate cypress tests into my app, but in order to perform e2e tests I need to interact with metamask. I am using the cypress-metamask plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-metamask), but cannot get it to work.

Running the tests returns the following error:

> cy.task('setupMetamask') failed with the following error:
>
> > request to http://localhost:9222/json/version failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222

This is the test:

```
describe('NFTicket', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.setupMetamask();
    cy.changeMetamaskNetwork('localhost')
    cy.visit('/')
  });

  it('is expected to display a sussess message', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=title]').should('contain.text', 'MetaMask Detected')
  });
  
});
```

This is how my cypress/plugins/index.js is configured:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('cypress-metamask/plugins')(on);
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = { isHeaded: true }, arguments_) => {
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      arguments_.args.push('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
      arguments_.args.push('--disable-background-timer-throttling');
      arguments_.args.push('--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows');
      arguments_.args.push('--disable-renderer-backgrounding');
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: is this only with chrome, did you try electron?

Comment: Only with chrome currently

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure the server is started,
You can try this  `127.0.0.1 localhost` in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: The server is definitely running

Answer (score -1):

In our project, we also encountered a problem using this library. I don't remember exactly what it was, but in general we couldn't solve it and then we changed it to [@synthetixio/synpress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@synthetixio/synpress). In our project with this library e2e tests run perfectly.

```
npm i @synthetixio/synpress

yarn add @synthetixio/synpress
```

A list of useful commands for working with metamask can be found [here](https://github.com/synthetixio/synpress/blob/master/support/index.d.ts).